Serialzing nested DateTimes using System.Text.Json
I am currently in the process of migrating from Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json.
I have a class that contains a string SerializedClass, which itself is a serialized representation of some other class:
public class MyClass
{
  // This is a serialized OtherClass instance
  public string SerializedClass { get; set; }
}

The other class (the serialized one) has some fields, among them a DateTime:
public class OtherClass
{
  public DateTime someKey { get; set; }
}

SerializedClass contains in it the DateTime representation in the following format: "\"someKey\": \"2023-02-22T12:05:07.2480000Z\"",, but I need to switch to the following format: \""someKey\": \"2023-02-22T12:05:07.248Z\"" (note the 4 omitted zeros at the end).
The existing Newtonsoft code does this by calling JObject.Parse(x.SerializedClass). A JObject is used because some json manipulations are being done, and the Parse method has the desired side-effect of changing the DateTime formats.
I am not sure how to achieve this using System.Text. I tried creating a custom JsonConverter<DateTime>, but that does not work since SerializedClass is a string, not a DateTime.
How do I parse a JsonObject (or some other System.Text equivalent to Newtonsoft's JObject) from a json, but have it parse nested serizlied DateTimes in the desired format?
I suppose some clever use of iterating the nodes in the JsonObject or something like that might work, but I feel like I may be missing a better, safer solution (settings, a custom converter, etc.).

I did not fully get your question. Is someKey part of SerializedClass and contains the DateTime as string repesentation or is SerializedClass a DateTime representation? ... In the first option System.Text.Json can handle both types of DateTime you specified.  https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zx5Frd

Martin, SerializedClass is a string, and that string happens to be the serialized json of a whole other class. For all intents and purposes, its value is "\"someKey\": \"2023-02-22T12:05:07.2480000Z\"", though in reality it has more key-value pairs serialized. I edited my question to include an example of the class structure.

@Gil that's not nested DateTime. Post the actual JSON text in the question. It looks like the JSON is bad. You can't even call it "nested JSON", another non-existent thing - you can't have raw attributes in JSON. A bug in whatever produced this tried to store another object as serialized JSON in a property instead of just storing the object in that property.

@Gil the existing Newtonsoft code does no way - JSON.NET wouldn't parse "someKey": "2023-02-22T12:05:07.2480000Z" because that's just not valid JSON string. It would parse {"someKey": "2023-02-22T12:05:07.2480000Z"}. Are you sure there isn't another bug in the JSON generator that breaks the code that covered up the previous bug?

@Gil  SerializedClass is a string that's the real bug. Store the actual object instead

Panagiotis, I cannot change SerizliedClass from string to the actual class that it represents. I am looking tor a solution within my constraints - SerialiedClass is a string, which is a big serialization, and some of the [serialized] values in it are DateTimes in a certain format, I need a different format. Newtonsoft.Json conveniently happens to change the format when JObject.Parse is called, and I am looking for a way to achieve this with System.Text.JSon

Couldn't get an answer, so ended up going Node by Node - if the value was successfully parsed as a DateTime, mutate it to a new string with the desired DateTime format.
Would love to hear a better solution if anyone has one, I feel like I might be missing something.

The only answer is that the JSON you have is bad. You didn't post the actual JSON so it's impossible for anyone to help you handle the broken JSON. This has nothing to do with formats or JSON.NET. All parsers can handle the ISO8601 format, whether it's 2023-02-22T12:05:07.2480000Z , 2023-02-22T12:05:07.248Z or 2023-02-22T12:05:07.248 +00:00

mutate it to a new string with the desired DateTime format. there's no such thing. DateTime is a binary value and the standard way of serializing dates in JSON is ISO8601. Instead of fixing problems it seems you're adding more bugs. The actual bug is  public string SerializedClass { get; set; }. Use the correct type instead and don't try to double-serialize. Make MyClass generic or make the property dynamic or object, and let both JSON.NET and STJ serialize the entire object

Not sure I understand why "the json I have is bad". The json value itself is not important, only that it is a serialization of some class, and that class has some DateTimes in it (serialized, of course, as it's all a big string), in a certain format, and I need those changed to another format. I cannot change SeralizedClass from string to any other type, unfortunately that is not an option.
